# Decrypting of AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding Error: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm getting **Given final block not properly padded** error while decrypting AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding cipher on large encrypted file.

I think this issue is caused by adding wrong initialization vector in **cipher.init()** method.

I can't read whole file at runtime, so i need to encrypt fixed-size blocks. At this point I'm creating IV and storing it to .txt file. But in decrypting method I'm using the same IV every decryption cycle. How should I change this?

**Encryption:**

```
void encrypt() throws Exception{
    char[] password = passwordText.getText().toCharArray();
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];

    /* Creating and saving salt */
    salt = saveSalt(salt);

    /* Securing password */
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    if (choosedFile != null) {
        /* Choosing algorithm for decryption */
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        /* Getting plain file */
        CipherInputStream fis = new CipherInputStream(new  FileInputStream(choosedFile), cipher);
        CipherOutputStream fos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(choosedFile+".encrypted"), cipher);

        /* Encrypting and Measuring */
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] rawText = new byte[128];
        int count;
        while((count = fis.read(rawText)) > 0) {
            System.out.println(count);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(rawText);
            fos.write(encryptedText, 0, count);
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        fis.close();
        fos.close();

        /* Creating initialization vector and storing*/
        byte[] iVector = cipher.getIV();
        saveIVector(iVector);

        text.setText(text.getText() + "File was encrypted in " + (stopTime - startTime) + "ms.\n");
    }

}
```

**Decryption:**

```
    void decrypt() throws Exception {
    /* Getting salt */
    byte[] salt = getSalt();
    /* Getting initialization vector */
    byte[] iVector = getIVector();
    /* Getting user password */
    char[] password = passwordText.getText().toCharArray();


    /* Securing password */
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    if (choosedFile != null) {

        /* Choosing algorithm for decryption */
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        /* Getting ciphered file */


        CipherInputStream fis = new CipherInputStream(new  FileInputStream(choosedFile), cipher);
        CipherOutputStream fos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(choosedFile+".decrypted"), cipher);

        /* Decrypting and Measuring */
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iVector));
        byte[] rawText = new byte[128];
        int count;
        while((count = fis.read(rawText)) > 0) {
                byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(rawText);
                fos.write(encryptedText, 0, count);
            }

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        fis.close();
        fos.close();
```

Comment: Since you are specifying PKCS#5 adding in both the encryption and decryption the error really is an error in the decryption due to incorrect parameters (key, iv, encrypted data). The decryption failed so the padding is also garbage. Re-work the question to just include encryption and provide the encrypted data in hex. Use small input to make it easy. provide a [mcve]. Since the error is associated with encryption strip out all the other code.

Comment: @zaph I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that both encryption and decryption algorithms worked just fine until I had to cut large file into fixed-size blocks. Ergo, I don't think examples of encrypted data are needed. However I tried to encrypt and decrypt small file. It ended up with same result. Still, you were right. Encryption is not working as it should, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream`, the streams handle all the calls to the cipher (that's why you pass the cipher to it on initialization). You just need to initialize it correctly, and stream the data through the stream, and the cipher stream will do the needed calls to `update()` and `doFinal()`. Remember to close the steams to trigger the `doFinal()`.

Currently your code passes the data through the cipher several times in an uncontrolled way, and the data is messed up.

Also, you only need a `CipherInputStream` for decrypt, and a `CipherOutputStream` for encrypt. In your current code you use both for both encrypt and decrypt.

Encrypt could be something like this (this don't handle the iv ..):

```
...     
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(choosedFile);
OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(choosedFile+".encrypted"), cipher);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}

is.close();
os.close();
...
```

Comment: I guess I know what do you want to say. But could you provide me some better example? I don't understand why I need only `CipherOutputStream` at encryption, when I need input chunk of file, encrypt it and then pass it to output. Then do it then same until I encrypted all chunks of file. I dont have whole raw 1GB data at runtime.

Comment: Thanks you! Worked for me like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Worried about "until I had to cut large file into fixed-size blocks".

Using "chunk" in place of "block" above because "block"has a specific meaning in block ciphers such as AES.

What are toy doing with the chunks, concatenating them?

With CBC mode, after the first block the the previous encrypted block value is effectively used as the IV for the next block. So when splitting and then concatenating the chunks the value of the last block of the previous chunk is the IV for the next chunk.

See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

Or are you doing something completely different?

Comment: As you can see above `byte[] rawText` represents these chunks of file. (Sorry for missleading name it should be something like rawChunkOfFile) I'm trying to encrypt this chunk and write it to output file. Than take another chunk and do the same until there is no chunk left. But i think, I should be using `cipher.update()` method somehow instead of `cipher.doFinal()`.

Comment: Yes use `cipher.update()`, it propogates the block chaining. Don't forget to call `cipher.final()`. See [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

Comment: I should use `cipher.update()` then write chunk to output and after `while()` I should call `cipher.final()`. Or should I call final on last chunk of file?

Comment: I'm still getting **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded** Error. But this time from `(count = fis.read(rawText)) > 0` at decryption method.